What does it mean: "Pull people up on small mistakes to make a point"?
Please can someone explain what does it mean: "Pull people up on small mistakes to make a point"?
I read it in a personality test, and didn't really understood what does it mean.

Please edit your question to include the source (where you saw or heard this) and some of the context around it. That will help you receive more relevant answers.

Pull someone up is an expression used in British English (and anyway not in American) to mean, roughly, scold, chastise. To make a point means in order to convey a particular message. Thus, for instance,

Finding his dirty clothes all over the floor, she picked them all up, folded them neatly, and placed them on his pillow to make a point.


Thank you very much!
